# If the universe is closed, does the twin paradox really matter?

Tags: special-relativity

By closed universe, I mean just something like 3-D analog of a closed ring or a sphere.

I think it can be one of arguments that the universe must not be closed. Is that right? The paradox is just the fruit of man's imagination that does not actually exist.

Comment: The universe is whatever the universe is. Physicists' arguments either reflect that, in which case they may be useful, or they don't, in which case they are simply false.

Answer (score 1):

No, these are independent ideas.  The twin 'paradox' is not actually a paradox, just a misconception.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38730/discussion-on-answer-by-anon0909-if-the-universe-is-closed-does-the-twin-parado).